# Covering one part of a bipartite set

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $A,B$ where $A$ consists of all 2-subsets of $[n]$,
$B$ consists of all 3-subsets of $[n]$ and the edges are defined by the inclusion relation.
I would like to know the smallest number of vertices in $A$ that cover all of $B$.
In other words: what is the size of the smallest subset $S$ of $A$ such that every vertex
of $B$ has an edge to $S$.

The first values seem to be $1,2,4,6,9,12,16$ (starting with $n=3$), but Sloane
gives too many hits for this pattern.

I know that the general problem is hard, but this specific one is highly symmetric,
so there may be a smart attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an equivalent problem: What is the minimum possible number of edges in an $n$-vertex graph with no independent set of size 3? Here any pair of vertices corresponds to a member of $A$, any set of 3 vertices corresponds to a member of $B$, and the edges correspond to members of $S$. But consider the complement of this problem: What is the maximum possible number of edges in an $n$-vertex graph with no $K_3$? This is exactly [Turán's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem), so your solution will be:

$$\left|E\left(\overline{T(n,2)}\right)\right| = \left \lfloor \frac{(n-1)^2}{4} \right \rfloor$$

Comment: Great, thanks Perry. I feel slightly ashamed to have overlooked this.